# Pressure in a fluid and force of gravity

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I have this moving fluid in a pipe. 
Let's consider the force P1A1 in the left face of the fluid portion before the movement. In a real scenario does the pressure P1 also contain a component of the gravitational field ? How is it possible to isolate the pressure of the fluid in the surface A1 from the gravitational field ?
(Does Feynman talk about this problem ?)

[image]

Comment: No, pressure does not have "components". The pressure might vary from one point to another, and the gravitational field might be responsible for a change of energy, but they are "initially independent". Then related by conservation of momentum. You might be using the Bernoulli equation to relate them "afterwards".

Comment: If you are saying that P1 varies with elevation (due to gravity) over cross section A, then you are correct.  What you are going to be using in your flow analysis is the average pressure over the cross section.

Comment: In this picture P1 refers to the pressure caused by the only fluid ?  Mhm but a this point what is the pressure caused by the fluid ?